# How to use Mathematica in Chrome extension?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, web-access, deployment, free-wolfram-engine, web

Now that the [wolfram engine is free](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) (for developers), I'd like to know how to use it within a chrome extension. It's [easy to make a chrome extension](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-chrome-extension-10-minutes-flat/), which is essentially just a JSON file with some javascript. But I'd like my chrome extension to run some function like an `Interpreter` or `ClassifierFunction` over the text in the div blocks of a page's HTML.

I have yet to find any examples of writing browser integration/applications with wolfram language so tutorial would be great, but any guidance or references would helpful.

Comment: The thing is kinda heavy duty to be building into a Chrome extension? Also might be a license violation? Assuming this would be a public extension. Otherwise doesn't it just depend on how one gets the HTML from the page? Past that you can just call `wolframscript` (assuming Chrome has permissions to do that)

Comment: [Native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) seems to be how Chrome plugins communicate with native applications. So the question then becomes, how do you communicate with Wolfram Engine using the standard input and output?

Comment: @b3m2a1 Right, but it's just a personal project, I'm not putting it on the chrome extension store.

Comment: @C.E. or how to use the wolfram python server as a remote call in javascript

Comment: To follow up on what @C.E. said, you just need to call into `wolframscript` then once you have a way to extract the HTML. If you need a persistent server you could do the python server, but that seems like a layer of unnecessary complexity.